# Receiving a 'coordinates must be an array of two or more positions' error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, geolocation, mapbox, turfjs

I'm using turf.js to create a line the shows the path of someone while their location is being tracked.

I have an array of coordinate arrays as shown in Turf.js (lineString) but I'm receiving this error:

```
Uncaught Error: coordinates must be an array of two or more positions
```

Vuejs -

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      lat: '',
      lng: '',
      locationData: [],
    }
  }
}
```

Line creation method -

```
targetTrackingLine() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(this.center !== this.defaultCoordinates) {
      this.locationData.push([this.lng, this.lat])
      turf.lineString([this.locationData], {name: 'line 1'});
    }
}, 1500)}
```

[What I see when I console my locationData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX3lD.png)

Does it have to do with this observer?

[Does it have to do with this observer?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmG5k.png)

Comment: i wonder that is that observer.

Comment: @vaira I don't understand your comment

Comment: '__ob__': Observer, one can see that in your image as third option

Comment: if locationData is already an array, should it not be  turf.lineString(this.locationData, {name: 'line 1'});

Comment: In the documentation for this, it shows it as this http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineString

And yes, what is this observer?

Comment: I think you are triple brackets, creating three-level nested array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `this.locationData` is an array then the input does not require extra brackets around it.

```
   turf.lineString(this.locationData, {name: 'line 1'});
```

Comment: In the documentation for this, it shows it as this http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineString, so this setup would be corrrect, I imagine

Comment: https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineString
your solution is turf.lineString([[[ ] [] ]], {name: 'line 1'});
you are creating three level nested brackets Array

Comment: I've updated my question. How does this read?

Comment: can you put this line 'turf.lineString(this.locationData, {name: 'line 1'});' in your solution and let me know the result.

Comment: When I do it that way, I get the same response and all the coordinates show in the same array... as in... `['-80.201445', '25.763674', '-80.201445', '25.763674', '-80.201445', '25.763674', __ob__: Observer]`

Comment: I am having a little toruble understanding how this is possible.
 this.locationData.push([this.lng, this.lat]) // implies that this.locationData is an array.
if you are pushing [this.lng, this.lat] in an array it should look like:
[['-80.201445', '25.763674']]

Comment: simple ex: 
let arr =  []
arr.push([1,2])

arr = [[1,2]]

Comment: Well, we know by their example that `turf.lineString([this must be classified as an array], {name: 'line 1'});` so it makes sense to remove the array from `this.locationData.push([this.lng, this.lat])` but for some reason that creates only one array? It really makes no sense

Comment: Unless `turf.lineString([this must be classified as an array], {name: 'line 1'});` doesn't need the array inside of it... but when I remove it, I still have the same issue

Comment: ['-80.201445', '25.763674', '-80.201445', '25.763674', '-80.201445', '25.763674', __ob__: Observer] can you share what you placed inside the console and where.

Comment: Ok. I went back and did your suggestion again, and this time I am receiving the right console data but no line or even point, and by my IDE's response, I need that array in there (it also is shown in the docs.) Is there a way to make locationData not an array from the outset then convert and load the data into a 'locationData' array?

Comment: can you share what is the "right console data", and also what you are putting in console.

Comment: I've shared it below (or is it above?) You should see the answer

Comment: this.locationData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.locationData))
I am not sure if this will do any good but it will make ur array apear normal

Comment: Ok, I've tried that in the place of the now gone array in turf.lineString() but I'm not seeing anything on my map. Strange

Answer (score 0):

[Correct console data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJH4y.png)

As you can see, the error is no longer there, but no line is showing up on my map.

Also, as you can see in my IDE, it seems I need at least THAT array in there

[With Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mOaT.png)

[Without array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbYIP.png)